# node.js socket.io How to emit to a particular client?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to "emit" a message to a particular client which is selected based on another message received in a different client, How do I do this?

I am thinking of joining each client to their own "room" and then broadcast. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**UPDATE for socket.io version 1.0 and above**

```
io.to(socketid).emit('message', 'whatever');
```

For older version:

You can store each client in an object as a property. Then you can lookup the socket based on the message:

```
var basket = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on("register", function(data) {
    basket[data.nickname] = socket.id;
  });
  socket.on("privmessage", function(data){
    var to = basket[data.to];
    io.sockets.socket(to).emit(data.msg);
  });
});
```

Not tested...but it should give you an idea

Comment: How does it work with reddiss? I want to do the same thing but in a distributed load balanced environment.

Comment: for the version 1.0, we need to use io.to(socketId).emit('pm', {});
like @Minho Lee said

Comment: @budsiya did you ever get it to work? I'm working on a similar problem, where I have multiple node processes running on a single server.

Comment: @budsiya, you mean `redis` ?

Comment: @Francesco This is very nice but you should expand the example, to help begginers grasp the concept. Or provide some links

Comment: socketId is actually a "room" now. so the client should subscribe for "roomUniqueId". and the server should know about it. no need to create an in-memory basket map.

Answer (score 17):

For socket.io version 1.0 use:

```
io.to(socketid).emit('message', 'whatever');
```

Answer (score 2):

Emitting to a particular client using a socketID.

**Server/ package: socket.io:**

```
io.to(socketID).emit('testEvent', 'yourMessage');
```

**Client/ package socket.io-client:**

```
io.sockets.on('connection',(socket) => {
  socket.on("testEvent", data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

You can get access the socketID in the following manner:

```
io.on('connection', (socket, next) => {
    const ID = socket.id // id property on the socket Object
})
```

It is simply a property on the `socket` object