# python socket.io How to emit to a particular client?

Tags: sockets, flask, websocket, python-socketio

there is a similar question for nodejs but I need for python also

[node.js socket.io How to emit to a particular client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110411/node-js-socket-io-how-to-emit-to-a-particular-client)

I want to broadcast a message to an specific client based on some condition  using socketio and flask from the connected clients.
Basically,

1. How I can find the connected clients in socket io?
2. How I can emit a message to an specific client?

**Sample code for broadcast**

```
@socket_.on('my_broadcast_event', namespace='/test')
def test_broadcast_message(message):
    session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
    emit('my_response',
         {'data': message['data'], 'count': session['receive_count']},
         broadcast=True)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423646/flask-socketio-emit-to-specific-user. Note that Flask-SocketIO uses python-socketio as a dependency.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flask socketio emit to specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423646/flask-socketio-emit-to-specific-user)